# Наследование и конструктор

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Здравствуйте, есть задача:

1. Создать класс "одномерный вектор размерности 4"
2. Создать соответствующие методы:

   - задания элементов матрицы;
   - вывода матрицы на экран;
   - нахождения максимального элемента матрицы;
3. Описать производный от него класс матрица 4 X 4 с соответствующими
   перегруженными методами. Создать объекты классов "матрица" и "одномерный вектор".
4. Найти максимальные элементы каждого объекта.

Одно из главных условий: должен быть конструктор. Я реализовал в конструкторе ввод массива, но теперь столкнулся с проблемой при наследовании конструктора,
в классе наследника.

Вот код:

```
using System;

namespace Laba4
{
    class Matrix
    {

        public Matrix(int[] arr)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            }

        }

        public void Output(int[] arr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your vector");
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                System.Console.Write(arr[i] + " ");
            }
        }

        public int Ymova(int[] arr)
        {
            int max = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (arr[i] > max) max = arr[i];

            }
            return max;

        }

    }

    class Matrix2d : Matrix
    {

        public Matrix2d(int[,] array) : base(array) // вот тут проблемка
        {

        }

    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array = new int[4];
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix(array);
            matrix.Output(array);
            Console.WriteLine("max = " + matrix.Ymova(array));

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Если делать без base оно выбивает ошибку что касается аргументов, как тут выйти из ситуации? Я же не могу передать двумерный массив в base.

Comment: У вашего задания, простите, глупое условие. Матрица с точки зрения ООП **не есть** частный случай вектора, поэтому ответом на вопрос «как впихнуть матрицу в подкласс вектора» будет «нормально никак, дизайн иерархии классов неверен».

Comment: и если даже наоборот наследоваться от двумерной матрицы к вектору?

Comment: Смотрите. Класс X является подклассом класса Y не тогда, когда у них есть общий код, а когда **X является частным случаем Y** и везде, где вы используете Y, можно без проблем использовать X. Например, если у вас есть классы Животное и Антилопа, то второй есть очевидный подкласс первого.

Comment: В вашем случае, одномерный массив не есть частный случай двумерной матрицы. Точно так же наоборот, двумерная матрица не есть частный случай одномерного массива. Так что никто из них по-правильному не должен быть подклассом другого.

Comment: Почитайте хорошую книжку по ООП. С вашим преподавателем вы, боюсь, ничему не научитесь.

Comment: @M-Misha-M с точки зрения математики вектор  - это матрица размера n*1, так что можно наследовать вектор от матрицы, однако для этого надо задавать размерность не жестко, а динамически, в конструкторе.

Comment: @RussCoder: Это в случае, если размеры неизменны. А если у матрицы есть метод `SetRowCount()`, что делать вектору?

Comment: @VladD я так понимаю, что вы предлагаете хранить вектор как матрицу 1*n, то есть как 1 строку, а метод `SetRowCount()` устанавливает количество строк, что для вектора неуместно. Тут я могу сказать лишь то, что это ошибка программной модели, так как такие вещи должны задаваться в конструкторе и быть неизменными . Нужна новая размерность  - создавайте новую матрицу, а не изменяйте размерность старой.

Comment: @RussCoder: Всё равно нехорошо. Для матрицы у вас будут методы `GetRowCount()` и `GetColCount()`, которые не имеют смысла для вектора. Прикажете юзерам не обращать на них внимания? Кстати говоря, проблема не нова: [вот](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem) и [вот](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CircleAndEllipseProblem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задание довольно бессмысленно на самом деле. В рамках этого задания разве что есть смысл сделать абстрактный класс с абстрактными же методами для вывода элементов массива и поиска максимального значения, а уже от него наследовать два класса - вектор и матрицу и для каждого написать свои реализации. Если ваш препод настаивает именно о наследовании матрицы от вектора, то он идиот - это можно сделать разве что костылями.

Плюс к тому же вы тут написали весьма хреновую реализацию с захардкоженными размерами массивов, передачей уже готового массива конструктору  и Console.ReadLine в конструкторе, по-хорошему от этого стоит избавиться

UPD

> тогда пожалуйста, просветите меня, может я действительно не прав, а как нужно делать чтобы не было хардкода в моем случае?

Просвещаю:

Во-первых, не стоит  прописывать размер массива прямо в цикле - это говнокодище чистой воды. У вас конструктор принимает некий массив любой длины. Допустим, массив, который вы передаете в конструктор, имеет не четыре, а три элемента. Это значит, что вы получите исключение. Иными словами, вы нигде и никак не указываете потенциальному пользователю вашего класса, что его конструктор ожидает  не просто какой-то массив, а массив из четырех элементов. Это крайне плохой подход. Раз уж вам нужен именно массив из четырех элементов, то тогда вовсе не нужно передавать его в конструктор, а нужно его в этом конструкторе создавать. Например так:

```
public Matrix()
{
    arr = new int[4]; // сам массив arr должен быть объявлен в классе
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)        
        arr[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());        
}
```

Во-вторых, если уж вам так обязательно иметь именно четыре элемента, то не надо прописывать это в десяти местах. Введите константу, присвойте ей нужное значение и используйте в циклах ее. Тогда вам не потребуется менять это магическое число 4 везде, где оно встречается (и при этом ломать голову, то ли самое число вы меняете, или это какое-то другое "четыре"). Например так:

```
public class Matrix 
{
    private const int Size = 4;
    private int[] arr = new int[Size];

    public Matrix()
    {            
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)            
            arr[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());             
    }
}
```

В-третьих, не нужно использовать никаких Console.ReadLine в конструкторе. Потому что консольному вводу вообще не место в конструкторе, а главное, потому что ваш класс не должен зависеть от класса Console. Более того, если метод Convert не сможет преобразовать строку в число (а это вполне частый случай, если, скажем, пользователь введет черт знает что), то вы получите исключение, которые вы опять-таки не обрабатываете. Если нужно как-то инициализировать массив, то либо передавайте в конструктор четыре отдельных значения извне, либо инициализируйте его случайными числами. Вариант с передачей массива не очень хорош, об этом я писал выше. Он требует проверки, что массив содержит именно 4 элемента, и, самое главное, никак не говорит пользователю об этом.

В-четвертых, взгляните на ваши методы - все они принимают массив целых чисел, и по факту ничего с ним не делают. Почему? Вы же должны находить наибольшие значения именно вашего вектора, а не какого попало массива, полученного в качестве параметра. Уберите их из параметров и используйте внутреннюю приватную переменную

Comment: тогда пожалуйста, просветите меня, может я действительно не прав, а как нужно делать чтобы не было хардкода в моем случае?

Comment: ааа вы о length говорите?

Comment: @M-Misha-M обновил ответ